# Trying to Load Page on Load instead of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm using this code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
        e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link

        $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) , function() {
            /* Content is now loaded */
            ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",10,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);
        });
    });
});
```

along with this:

```
<li><a href="Help.html" class="dynamicLoad">HELP</a></li>
```

To load pages when the link is clicked.

I would like to know how do I add to the current script so that I can load a page the minute the page loads up, while keeping it working the way it already is? I'd like to load a page named "Homepage.html"

Comment: A better idea might be to do that on the server side if you need it on the page when the user first sees it, any reason why that might not be suitable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#MainWrapper').load('Homepage.html');
});
</script>
```

Or if you still need that callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#MainWrapper').load('Homepage.html', function() {
        ThumbnailScroller('tsv_container','vertical',10,800,'easeOutCirc',0.4,500);
    });
});
</script>
```